# Ignore property mapping by accessbility in Fluent NHibernate AutoMapper

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, automapping

I have the following class which I am mapping using Fluent NHibernate's AutoMapper. I do not want the list items publically modifiable so have a public `IEnumerable` backed by an `IList` which can be populated internally or by NHibernate.

I want NHibernate to map `teamMembers` to a column named `TeamMembers`. I also want FNH to ignore the `TeamMembers` property on this class.

```
public class Team : Entity
{
    protected internal virtual IList<Person> teamMembers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> TeamMembers { get { return teamMembers;} }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you tell NHibernate's Autopersistence model to ignore your property:

```
var cfg = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(configurer)
            .Mappings(m =>
                        {
                            m.AutoMappings.Add(AutoMap.Assemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
                                .Override<Team>(map => map.IgnoreProperty(team => team.TeamMembers)));
                        });
```

You would then have just what you want.